# How can I install the Amazon MP3 app?

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Motorola Backflip running on AT&T with Android 1.5. I previously had a G1 with which I used Amazon MP3 all the time to buy music. However, Amazon MP3 doesn't come on the Backflip and isn't in the Market. Where can I find it to install?

Also, is there a reason it isn't on the market? My guess was because AT&T wants me to use their proprietary app.

Answer (score 4):

Xda-developers has a link in [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=713649), grabbed from a cc-May-2010 Froyo ROM.

Found it in [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.amazon.mp3) and [CyrKet.](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.amazon.mp3/)

Also, it IS in the market as of Sept 14, 2010 on my Incredible. Good luck linking to that one.

Comment: Using CyrKet results in a "not found on Android Marketplace" message.  Is it possible AT&T has the application blocked?

Comment: that would be.... weird. AT&T just wants to lock-down TO the AndroidMarkter, IIRC.